# Mailchimp Archive get more than 20 results

Tags: api, url, mailchimp

I am using Mailchimp's archive URL in PHP -- I am simply fetching the URL and displaying it as it sits, in order to white lable the funky URL IE

```
https://us17.campaign-archive.com/home/?u=xxxxxyyyyyxxxxyyyy&id=xxxxyyyyyxxxxyy
```

In doing so I have read through both the [Archive](https://mailchimp.com/help/about-email-campaign-archives-and-pages/) and API documentation, and have found nothing on the parameter for row count.  It defaults to 20 as stated in the Archive docs, but I know I have seen archives with a larger row count than that.  Is anyone familiar enough with the URL parameters used by MailChimp to increase the row count, to say, 100?  IE

```
https://us17.campaign-archive.com/home/?u=xxx&id=yyy&count=100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a problem for years. Even in 2022 there is still no known way for an end-user to get more than past 20 issues from mailchimp, they simply refuse to add/allow that ability.

However the newsletter creator can go into their backend and generate/enable a javascript API that has the &show= parameter, which can be increased.

https://mailchimp.com/help/add-an-email-campaign-archive-to-your-website/

Again, only the campaign creator can do this, not some random end-user/reader.